# Oracle full error message in log

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, exception

I'm trying to get the full error message from oracle.

For example - I have a very long procedure that doing a lot of manipulation on

a lot of objects, and in my log I got the error

> object no longer exist.

And this is my insert to the log (even it is a generally question - not specific to this example):

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
       v_errno := sqlcode;
       V_ERRMSG := SQLERRM;
       INSERT INTO ERR_TABLE (ERROR_NUMBER, ERROR_MESSAGE,PROGRAM#)
       VALUES (V_ERRNO, V_ERRMSG,'MY_PKG');
       COMMIT;
```

The problem is that I don't know which table it talking about - because this

information doesn't exsits.

Is there a way to get it?

I guess that oracle save it in some place.

thanks!

Comment: show us the code of log file insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For internal logging (not only for errors) I use a procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE Put(
        LogMessage IN T_LOG_ENTRIES.LOG_MESSAGE%TYPE,
        ErrCode IN T_LOG_ENTRIES.LOG_ERROR_CODE%TYPE DEFAULT 0) IS

    ErrorStack T_LOG_ENTRIES.LOG_ERROR_STACK%TYPE;
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN

    IF ErrCode <> 0 THEN
        ErrorStack := DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE();
        ErrorStack := SQLERRM(ErrCode) || CHR(13) || ErrorStack;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO T_LOG_ENTRIES 
        (LOG_DATE, LOG_MESSAGE, LOG_ERROR_CODE, LOG_ERROR_STACK) 
    VALUES 
        (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LogMessage, ErrCode, ErrorStack);
    COMMIT;
END Put;
```

`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE()` provides the full error stack. You should use `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` since transactions are rolled back in case of exception, i.e. your log message would be deleted also.

Then you can use the procedure for example as this:

```
BEGIN
...
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   Put('Error in my procedure', sqlcode);
END;
```

Comment: ok, that look good. And I see that it's only for online exceptions. Is there something like that for offline errors?

Comment: In your answer the solution is to change the code for catch the full exception in the next time - I'm asking if there is a way to see the information on exceptions of process the already finish it's run and i didn't use the dbms_utility yet.

Comment: I still don't get it. If a procedure (or more precise a PL/SQL block) finishes then there is no exception. In case of exception you can forward it to logging table.

Comment: yes. I can do it, and it will help for the future. But if i have a procedure that run yesterday - I want to understand what is the exception that raised yesterday, not in the future. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No way, in this case the exception is gone. Unless you store the error stack somewhere else, it will disappear forever when you leave the PL/SQL block.